# neovim error Windows 10 UltiSnips with python 3

Tags: neovim

I receive this error every time I try to write code in nvim, in any file it does not matter if it is not python, I just installed vim and what I did is copy a repository, I don't know which part could be wrong, also mention that the paths are /user/.vim, and that the repository that I clone for this is from a person with mac.

[image]

This is the UltiSnips.vim:

```
if exists("b:did_autoload_ultisnips")
    finish
endif
let b:did_autoload_ultisnips = 1

" Also import vim as we expect it to be imported in many places.
py3 import vim
py3 from UltiSnips import UltiSnips_Manager

function! s:compensate_for_pum() abort
    """ The CursorMovedI event is not triggered while the popup-menu is visible,
    """ and it's by this event that UltiSnips updates its vim-state. The fix is
    """ to explicitly check for the presence of the popup menu, and update
    """ the vim-state accordingly.
    if pumvisible()
        py3 UltiSnips_Manager._cursor_moved()
    endif
endfunction

function! UltiSnips#Edit(bang, ...) abort
    if a:0 == 1 && a:1 != ''
        let type = a:1
    else
        let type = ""
    endif
    py3 vim.command("let file = '%s'" % UltiSnips_Manager._file_to_edit(vim.eval("type"), vim.eval('a:bang')))

    if !len(file)
       return
    endif

    let mode = 'e'
    if exists('g:UltiSnipsEditSplit')
        if g:UltiSnipsEditSplit == 'vertical'
            let mode = 'vs'
        elseif g:UltiSnipsEditSplit == 'horizontal'
            let mode = 'sp'
        elseif g:UltiSnipsEditSplit == 'tabdo'
            let mode = 'tabedit'
        elseif g:UltiSnipsEditSplit == 'context'
            let mode = 'vs'
            if winwidth(0) <= 2 * (&tw ? &tw : 80)
                let mode = 'sp'
            endif
        endif
    endif
    exe ':'.mode.' '.escape(file, ' ')
endfunction

function! UltiSnips#AddFiletypes(filetypes) abort
    py3 UltiSnips_Manager.add_buffer_filetypes(vim.eval("a:filetypes"))
    return ""
endfunction

function! UltiSnips#FileTypeComplete(arglead, cmdline, cursorpos) abort
    let ret = {}
    let items = map(
    \   split(globpath(&runtimepath, 'syntax/*.vim'), '\n'),
    \   'fnamemodify(v:val, ":t:r")'
    \ )
    call insert(items, 'all')
    for item in items
        if !has_key(ret, item) && item =~ '^'.a:arglead
            let ret[item] = 1
        endif
    endfor

    return sort(keys(ret))
endfunction

function! UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet() abort
    py3 UltiSnips_Manager.expand()
    return ""
endfunction

function! UltiSnips#ExpandSnippetOrJump() abort
    call s:compensate_for_pum()
    py3 UltiSnips_Manager.expand_or_jump()
    return ""
endfunction

function! UltiSnips#ListSnippets() abort
    py3 UltiSnips_Manager.list_snippets()
    return ""
endfunction

function! UltiSnips#SnippetsInCurrentScope(...) abort
    let g:current_ulti_dict = {}
    let all = get(a:, 1, 0)
    if all
      let g:current_ulti_dict_info = {}
    endif
    py3 UltiSnips_Manager.snippets_in_current_scope(int(vim.eval("all")))
    return g:current_ulti_dict
endfunction

function! UltiSnips#SaveLastVisualSelection() range abort
    py3 UltiSnips_Manager._save_last_visual_selection()
    return ""
endfunction

function! UltiSnips#JumpBackwards() abort
    call s:compensate_for_pum()
    py3 UltiSnips_Manager.jump_backwards()
    return ""
endfunction

function! UltiSnips#JumpForwards() abort
    call s:compensate_for_pum()
    py3 UltiSnips_Manager.jump_forwards()
    return ""
endfunction

function! UltiSnips#AddSnippetWithPriority(trigger, value, description, options, filetype, priority) abort
    py3 trigger = vim.eval("a:trigger")
    py3 value = vim.eval("a:value")
    py3 description = vim.eval("a:description")
    py3 options = vim.eval("a:options")
    py3 filetype = vim.eval("a:filetype")
    py3 priority = vim.eval("a:priority")
    py3 UltiSnips_Manager.add_snippet(trigger, value, description, options, filetype, priority)
    return ""
endfunction

function! UltiSnips#Anon(value, ...) abort
    " Takes the same arguments as SnippetManager.expand_anon:
    " (value, trigger="", description="", options="")
    py3 args = vim.eval("a:000")
    py3 value = vim.eval("a:value")
    py3 UltiSnips_Manager.expand_anon(value, *args)
    return ""
endfunction

function! UltiSnips#CursorMoved() abort
    py3 UltiSnips_Manager._cursor_moved()
endf

function! UltiSnips#LeavingBuffer() abort
    let from_preview = getwinvar(winnr('#'), '&previewwindow')
    let to_preview = getwinvar(winnr(), '&previewwindow')

    if !(from_preview || to_preview)
        py3 UltiSnips_Manager._leaving_buffer()
    endif
endf

function! UltiSnips#LeavingInsertMode() abort
    py3 UltiSnips_Manager._leaving_insert_mode()
endfunction

function! UltiSnips#TrackChange() abort
    py3 UltiSnips_Manager._track_change()
endfunction

function! UltiSnips#RefreshSnippets() abort
    py3 UltiSnips_Manager._refresh_snippets()
endfunction
" }}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is mostly because you don't have the pynvim Python package installed. Do a `pip install pynvim` and it should work.

Be careful because I couldn't make it work with latest version of python (3.9), as it says it needs Build Tools for C++.

Comment: I have that same version, what could I do?

Comment: The issue with that is that it asks you for C++ Build Tools, you can download them [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/). But it is several GB of tools just for this, so I would opt either for downgrading Python or deactivating Ultisnips if you don't really need it, because the issue is caused by a dependency package without wheel support for Python 3.9 (see [this issue](https://github.com/python-greenlet/greenlet/issues/200))

Comment: I put it there because it was in recommendations, but the truth is I don't know what it is for, could you detail that to me? And how would I uninstall it? Should I remove it from the plug?

Comment: The UltiSnips package helps you work with snippets, that is, that if you put some piece of text and you press <Tab> or any other binding key, it expands to a more complete piece of code. For example, if in markdown I type link and I expand it, it shows `[]()`, that is the way to put a link in markdown. About uninstalling, it depends on the plugin manager you used to install it. For example, with vimplug you can just comment the line in the init.vim and run :PlugClean